# Embed TypeScript code in an HTML document

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to embed TypeScript code in a web page? I want to embed TypeScript code inside script tags, like this (so that it is automatically compiled to Javascript):

```
<script type = "text/typescript">
    //TypeScript code goes here
</script>
```

Comment: It's possible if you use a run-time compiler, but why in the world would you want to? TypeScript is designed to compile to JavaScript, and translating it at run-time will give you a performance hit.

Comment: @PeterOlson There are already some JavaScript libraries that can compile TypeScript to JavaScript (as mentioned below). Are they both considered to be "runtime compilers"?

Comment: Yes, those are runtime compilers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually there are several projects that allow you to use TypeScript code like that - [TypeScript Compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile), [ts-htaccess](https://github.com/ComFreek/ts-htaccess).

The catch here is that .ts code should be compiled into JavaScript - it can be done either at client-side (slow; the whole TSC should be loaded into the client as well) or at server-side (obviously faster, and it's far easier to leverage the cache on the compiled code).

Answer (score 18):

This is a version I wrote that **directly** uses the version from Microsoft/TypeScript/master so it always stays up to date: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

You can even point `ts` to any other TypeScript version you might have and it will work fine

Comment: Any idea what typescriptServices.js is now?  `https://rawgit.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/lib/typescriptServices.js` no longer exists.  And I can't find anything like it at `https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScripthttps://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript`.  The module migration March 2023 probably changed it all.

Answer (score 6):

A JavaScript library has already been developed for this purpose - it's called [TypeScript Compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile), and it allows typescript to be embedded in HTML (as shown above.)

Comment: Please consider the implications of this before you use it - it is an awesome project, but will slow down your website if you use it for a production app or site.

Comment: @SteveFenton I only intend to use it for the purpose of testing my Typescript code.

Comment: Grand - perfect use of a browser-based compiler!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this specifically for the purpose of compiling TypeScript in the browser so that I could write quick and simple examples to share.

https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/text-typescript

Usage,

```js
<script type="text/typescript">
    // Your TypeScript code here
</script>
```

And include dependencies.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typescript@5.3.3"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/text-typescript@1.3.0"></script>
```

A complete example you can copy/paste into a HTML doc and try locally.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>"text/typescript" example</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Transpiling and executing TypeScript in the browser" />
        <style>
            body {
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0px;
                font-size: 15vw;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/typescript">
            function foo(bar: string) {
                return "Hello " + bar;
            }

            let baz = "World!";

            document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = foo(baz);
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typescript@5.3.3"></script>
        <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/text-typescript@1.3.0"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And you can see it working here, right now, today.

https://editor.sbcode.net/f1f4b5a73ec40283d1ddb37bb1e71f7e4e31b487