# Is it possible using typescript by auto compiler js file?

Tags: typescript

i want use typescript file like this:

`<script type="text/typescript">
// ...
</script>`

I found this: `https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html` . This can compile typescript. Which is this compiler? I guess this is monaco i tried it but gives `Uncaught TypeError: editor.getModel(...).getMode(...).getEmitOutput is not a function(…)`
Is there compiler?
Sorry for my bad English.
Edit: I found compilers. But their typescript versions is old.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed TypeScript code in an HTML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015899/embed-typescript-code-in-an-html-document)

Comment: Well, is there compiler of newest version TypeScript?

Comment: There's a [pull request](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile/pull/9) for typescript compile for the newest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version I wrote that **directly** uses the version from Microsoft/TypeScript/master so it always stays up to date: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

```
<script type="text/typescript">
    setTimeout(()=>console.log('hello'));
</script>
```

You can even point `ts` to any other TypeScript version you might have and it will work fine

Comment: I tried this. Can you look this issue, please?: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script/issues/2