# Is it possible to parse an HTML import file for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, custom-element, html-imports

I'm working with custom elements. A lot of these (especially libraries like Polymer) use HTML imports to load the component.

Most elements involve some CSS, some HTML and some scripts, and these can be separate `.css` and `.js`/`.ts`, often with embedded HTML in strings (or React/Preact `.tsx` files).

There's a more elegant solution using HTML imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-component.html">
```

And then in `my-component.html`:

```
...
<template>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
    <p>HTML content!</p>
</template>
<script>
    // Javascript to create custom element
</script>
...
```

I can use TypeScript externally with a separate `.ts` file, but that's a little messy. What I want to do is replace `my-component.html` with `my-component.tshtml` - a file that looks almost identical, but that has TypeScript instead of Javascript and that transpiles to the `.html` version in exactly the same way as `.ts` or `.tsx` files.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Supersharp - so my compile-time TS is parsed at run-time by the server? That kind of defeats the point of having TS in the first place. If I was going to go down that route I'd have a regular `.ts` file and then have a post-build step that inserted it into the `.html` file, but that the bit I refer to as messy in the question. I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Not at all. I wanted to say I didn't understand you question but I see my comment is worse so I will delete it! Are you looking for a tool like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015899/embed-typescript-code-in-an-html-document ?

Comment: @Supersharp not really - that question (and the selected action) are looking for runtime TypeScript compilation. That somewhat defeats the point of TypeScript and is useless for HTML import, as the whole point of them is grouping together HTML, CSS and script into a single fast download - an extra parsing step and library would completely nerf that.

Comment: OK so what you looking for is a parser that will generate inline javascript from inline typescript at compile time, isn't it? If so, a workaround could be to use a postbuild tool like gulp/grunt to concatenate HTML, CSS, JS in a single HTML file.

Comment: @Supersharp yes, exactly that. I can add post build command line stuff to do it, but that's messy and breaks map files. I'm wondering what the best way to do it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best way to do this, but what I would do is create a script that :

1. Parse the *.tshtml* file for `<script>` content.
2. Call the TypeScript compiler to transpile the content to JavaScript.
3. Inject the result in replacement of the `<script>` element content.
4. Save the modified file as *.html*.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to write a gulp task that does just that (if I do I'll share it) but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful code in the link in comments. Even if libs are client-side, some part could be reused in the server side... good luck anyway!