# Typescript: how to setup a button that clears score?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

In my index.html I have this button:

`<button class="restart-current-game">Restart current game</button>`

And I have this code in my `game.ts` file:

```
 restartCurrentGame() {
    score = 0;
    alert("Score is back to 0");
  }
```

How can I call this function by clicking the button?

Comment: If you have a different question, please don't edit this question and invalidate answers. Instead, post a new question

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event listener to the [on click event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)  of the button, then connect that button to your restartCurrentGame() function.

Your typescript won't be accepted by the browser by default since it only understands javascript so you will need to [to transpile your typescript into javascript](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/compiling-typescript-to-javascript.html) or use a package manager (like node.js) to [install a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015899/embed-typescript-code-in-an-html-document) like typescript-compile to run that code directly in a script tag.

EDIT:

I see that you've completely changed the question. Make a seperate post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may listen to `dblclick` event:

```js
document.querySelector('.player-name').addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
  this.outerHTML = `<input value="${this.innerHTML}">`
})
```

```html
 <b class="player-name">Player one</b>
```

Comment: Hello, I edited the question. Sorry, I thought that code that I pasted here first will be enough.

Comment: How can I save the given value?

Comment: On client side, you may use cookies or local storage; on server side, it depends what tools you're using

Answer (score 0):

You may have an input with a display none style. the b element will appear will have a double click event attached to it.

When the element will be doubled click, we will change the b element style to display none and the input style to display block.

```js
function onDblClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#hidden-input').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
 <b ondblclick="onDblClick(event)" class="player-name">Player one</b>
 <input id="hidden-input" style="display:none;" type="text" />
```

Comment: Hello, I edited the question. Sorry, I thought that code that I pasted here first will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read more about Typescript meaning because it's just a way to write javascript with a strict syntax but it's compiled to javascript so to execute it you need a compiler.

#### Using `b` tag

****Playground**: https://jsfiddle.net/youdede/2fjhqyav/45/**

If you are forced to use the `b` tag you can use the attribute `contenteditable`:

```
<b class="player-name" id="player-ID" ondblclick = "changeName('player-ID')" contenteditable="false">Player ID</b>
```

and your javascript function can be like this:

```
let changeName = (id)=>{
    let el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.focus();
  el.contentEditable = (el.contentEditable === 'false') ? "true" : "false";
}
```

#### Using `input` instead of `b` tag

**Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/youdede/2fjhqyav/23/**

*This is the best solution in my opinion*. You can use an `input` tag with `readonly` attribute and on `ondblclick` listener:

```
<input type="text" class="player-name" id="player-ID" value="Player N" ondblclick = "changeName('player-ID')" readonly>
```

Your `ondblclick` function (I called `changeName(id)`) can be like this:

```
let changeName = (id)=>{
  let readonly = document.getElementById(id).readOnly;
  document.getElementById(id).readOnly = !readonly;
}
```

To better display the 2 statuses of your input, you can define your css like this:

```
.player-name[readonly]{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I edited the question. Sorry, I thought that code that I pasted here first will be enough. As you can see I have multiple elements that have the same class (player-name)

Comment: Updated ;) I just added an id that identifies the player and allows you to link that name change to that specific player.

Comment: Seems good but how can I change the value of my <b> element to the given value?

Comment: Can you change the b element with that input element directly?

Comment: No, I would like to leave it as it is.

Comment: Just replied, using contenteditable attribute.